# Arrows between two tables

Tags: tables, arrows

I'd like to connect two cells from different tables using arrows. How can this be achieved?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Are there any restrictions in terms of the packages you're allowed (or want to) use? For example, this is easy-peasy using `tikz`.

Comment: no restrictions, i haven't used tikz, is it possible to animate when drawing with tikz?, i am using beamer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a couple of different ways to do this with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,draw,inner sep=1ex] (A) at (0,1)
{minus\nodepart{two}times\nodepart{three}transpose};

\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=5,draw,inner sep=1ex] (B) at (3,1)
{mmul\nodepart{two}mmuli\nodepart{three}sub\nodepart{four}subi\nodepart{five}transpose};
\draw[->] (A.text east) -- (B.three west);
\draw[->] (A.text east) -- (B.four west);
\draw[->] (A.two east) -- (B.text west);
\draw[->] (A.two east) -- (B.two west);
\draw[->] (A.three east) -- (B.five west);
\node (C) [below=of A]{Matrix Class};
\node[below= .5cm of B,text width=2cm,align=center]{Double Matrix\\ Class};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,nodes={draw, minimum size=.65cm, text width=2cm,align=center}] at (0,1)
{
minus\\
times\\
transpose\\
};
\matrix (B) [matrix of nodes,nodes={draw, minimum size=.65cm, text width=2cm,align=center}] at (4,1)
{
mmul\\
mmuli\\
sub\\
subi\\
transpose\\
};

\draw[->] (A-1-1.east) -- (B-3-1.west);
\draw[->] (A-1-1.east) -- (B-4-1.west);
\draw[->] (A-2-1.east) -- (B-1-1.west);
\draw[->] (A-2-1.east) -- (B-2-1.west);
\draw[->] (A-3-1.east) -- (B-5-1.west);

\node (C) [below=of A]{Matrix Class};
\node[below= .25cm of B,text width=2cm,align=center]{Double Matrix\\ Class};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thanks a lot it's exactly what i want, can you refer me to any good tutorials for learning this stuff?

Comment: @user895657 The TikZ manual (written by the same person who developed Beamer) has lots of good tutorials.  There are also plenty of great examples of all sorts of TikZ solutions ranging from simple to extraordinary here on the site.

Comment: @AlanMunn How can I put the arrow on the "north" or top of the table and connect it to the top of the next table?

Comment: @kolonel I'm not quite sure what you want. Do you want an arrow between the top of the 'minus' in the first table and the 'minus' in the second table?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\sffamily 

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cw{c}{8mm}c}[cell-space-limits=4pt]
            && \Block[hvlines]{5-1}{} mmul \\
            && mmuli \\
  \Block[hvlines]{3-1}{}
  minus     && sub \\
  times     && subi \\
  transpose && transpose \\
  \Block{}{Matrix\\ class} 
            && \Block{}{DoubleMatrix\\ class}
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->, > = LaTeX]
    \draw (4.5-|2) -- (1.5-|3) ; 
    \draw (3.5-|2) -- (3.5-|3) ; 
    \draw (3.5-|2) -- (4.5-|3) ; 
    \draw (5.5-|2) -- (5.5-|3) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]